# I want to send something in a POST command, without the user entering that value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, hapi.js

I am using mongoDB and Hapi to create a REST API. I am trying to be able to pass info into the database from the program itself.

For example, 
I have a payload that is configured as so:

```
config: {
  validate: {
      payload : {
          var_a: Joi.string(),
          var_b: Joi.number(),
          var_c Joi.string(),
          var_d: Joi.string(), //IMEI
          var_e: Joi.string(),
          var_f: Joi.string(),
          DONT WANT TO ENTER: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()),
          var_g: random_schema
    }
  }
}
```

I have code that would generate the array, but I am unable to pass it into the payload and see the information in my database. How could I do something like this? And we are sadly not using Express for this project. Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Can you expand on your question a bit? http://mph-web.de/build-a-restful-api-using-hapi-js-and-mongodb/ Seems to explain it very well, and has been updated recently.

Comment: Maybe it was a bit vague. So, I actually did follow that tutorial. It is very well put together. However, the issue I'm running into is delivering the payload to the database in a JSON format without the user entering one of the sub categories. I want that information to be provided to the database by the program itself.

Comment: @G.Curbelo in fact it's super simple - essentials of adding fields to object. `const data = request.payload; data.subCategory = 'smartphones';` or just using `Object.assign`. Even with Express You would have  such question. That means You rush into StackOverflow for stupid-simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend You to watch tutorials or read documentations about `hapi` framework.

You're asking about basics of framework (using hapi) and JS language (assigning/extending object).

This example must cover Your question:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Joi = require('joi');

const server = new Hapi.Server();  
server.connection({  
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080
});

server.route({  
  method: 'POST',
  path:'/devices/smartphones',
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: {
          var_a: Joi.string(),
          var_b: Joi.number(),
          var_c Joi.string(),
          var_d: Joi.string(), //IMEI
          var_e: Joi.string(),
          var_f: Joi.string(),
          DONT WANT TO ENTER: Joi.array().items(Joi.number()),
          var_g: random_schema
      }
    }
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        const data = Object.assign({}, 
          request.payload, 
          {
            category: 'devices',
            subCategory: 'smartphones'
          }
        );

        // save payload to db
        db.collection("collectionNameHere").insertOne(data, (error) => {
          if(error) { 
            console.log(error);
            return reply('oops...').code(500);
          } 
          reply().code(200);
        });
    }
  }
});

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
let db;
MongoClient.connect(url, (error, dbConnection) => {
  if (error) throw error;

  console.log('Connected to database');
  db = dbConnection;

  server.start(error => {
    if (error) throw error;

    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
  });
});
```

P.S. Example taken and modified from [here](https://lucamezzalira.com/2015/12/07/hapi-js-and-mongodb/) and [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-set-response-status-code)

What kind of db driver You'll use or will pick `mongoose` it's up to You.

Comment: The problem isn't in creating a POST request, as I can already do that. The issue I'm running into is delivering the payload to the database in a JSON format without the user entering one of the sub categories. I want that information to be provided to the database by the program itself.